# $X^{T}AX$ and $BX$ are independent when $BA=0$

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

Suppose $X \sim \mathcal{N}_k(0,I_k)$. Let $A$ be a $k \times k$ symmetric idempotent matrix and $B$ be a $l\times k$ matrix of full row rank. Show that if $BA=0$, then $X^{T}AX$ and $BX$ are independent.

I approached the problem in this way. Let $C=\begin{pmatrix}A \\ B\end{pmatrix}$. Then $$\mbox{cov}(CX) = CC^{T}= \begin{pmatrix} AA^T & AB^{T}\\ BA & BB^{T}\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} A^2 & 0\\ 0 & BB^{T}\end{pmatrix}$$
Now one may say that since $X$ is a multivariate normal random variable, due to affine transformation, $CX$ is also under same class of random variables. Hence normality ensures $AX$ and $BX$ are independent. Hence so is $X^{T}AX (= (AX)^{T}(AX))$ and $BX$.

But we were taught about multivariate normals with non-singular variance covariance matrix. I only have this tool: ($D$ is $m\times k$ matrix with full row rank)
$$X\sim \mathcal{N}_k(0,I_k) \implies DX \sim \mathcal{N}_{m}(0, DD^{T})$$
Can anybody prove it using this only?

Comment: What is $X \sim \mathcal{N}_k(0,I_k)$?

Comment: X follows multivariate normal with mean vector $0$ and variance-covariance matrix $I_k$. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Notation_and_parametrization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I somewhat figured it out after talking to my teacher.

Let $\mbox{rank} A=m$. Let $u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_m$ be $m$ linearly independent columns of $A$. Let $U=\begin{pmatrix} u_1^T\\ u_2^T \\ \vdots \\ u_m^T\end{pmatrix}$. Since $A$ is symmetric $u_1^T,u_2^T,\ldots,u_m^T$ forms a basis of row space of $A$. Hence $A=VU$ for some $V$. Since $BA=0$, Therefore, $u_i$ is orthogonal to all the rows of $B$. We form the matrix $C=\begin{pmatrix}B \\ U\end{pmatrix}$. By previous discussion, $C$ has full row rank ($=l+m$) .  Now applying the result mentioned in the original post, and calculating the covariances, we have $BX$ and $UX$ are independent. Since $(V(UX))^TV(UX)=X^TAX$, we have $BX$ and $X^TAX$ are independent.

Comment: An easier proof is using the fact that $\textbf{A}$ is idempotent so that $\textbf{A}^T\textbf{A} = \textbf{A}$. Write $$\textbf{x}^T\textbf{A} \textbf{x} = \textbf{x}^T\textbf{A}^T\textbf{A} \textbf{x} = \parallel \textbf{A} \textbf{x} \parallel^2.$$
It suffices to show $\textbf{Ax}$ and $\textbf{Bx}$ are independent if $\textbf{BA}= \textbf{0},$ which is obviously true.